# Python watchdog is not terminating when closing wxPython window

Tags: python, windows, python-multiprocessing, python-watchdog

I have an app which contains a wxPython GUI which launches a watchdog observer and a python process on initialization.

```
class MonitorApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.App.__init__(self, True, 'monitor_stderr.log', False, False)

        self.q = Queue()
        self.m = Queue()
        self.e = Queue()

        monitor_handler = DirectoryMonitorHandler(self.q)
        self.folder_monitor = polling.PollingObserver()
        self.folder_monitor.schedule(monitor_handler, source, recursive = True)
        self.folder_monitor.start()

        self.backlog_manager = BacklogManager(self.q, self.m, self.e)
        self.backlog_manager.start()
```

I am closing the wxPython window via this wx.TaskBarIcon callback method:

```
def onClickExit(self, event):
    app.keepGoing = False
    app.DestroyChildProcess()
    self.RemoveIcon()
    self.Destroy()
    self.frame.Destroy()
```

where DestroyChildProcess is:

```
def DestroyChildProcess(self):
    self.folder_monitor.stop()
    self.folder_monitor.join()
    self.backlog_manager.terminate()
```

Note that BacklogManager is a multiprocessing Process subclass. The problem that I am having is that when I close  the wxPython GUI window, I am still seeing two pythonw.exe processes in the Windows task manager. There are three possibilities:

1. I am not terminating the GUI process correctly. (Not sure if it is a process)
2. I am not terminating the watchdog observer correctly.
3. I am not terminating the backlog_manager process correctly.

From playing around with the code, it appears the call "self.backlog_manager.terminate()" does seem to work correctly, leaving ONE instance of pythonw.exe running.

Is there a way for me to terminate or stop all pythonw.exe processes correctly? What am I doing wrong?

Edit - Upon further investigation, it seems that this might be an issue with the .bat script that I am using to start my python script. I am essentially using pythonw.exe and START /B to hide the command line window.

```
cd %~dp0
START /B .\Modules\statusWindow.pyw
```

It seems that when I start the script with the following:

```
cd %~dp0
.\Modules\statusWindow.py
```

When I close the command line window, all the windows task manager processes end. I suspect that this is likely an issue with pythonw.exe or the way I'm ending the process.

Answer (score 0):

on windows I know terminate works unreliably at best what I would do is something like

```
class BacklogManager(multiprocessing.Process):
     _should_exit = multiprocessing.Value("b",0)
     def terminate(self):
         self._should_exit.value = 1
     def run(self):
        #instead of while True
        while not self._should_exit.value:
             do_work()
```

this will cause it to properly exit when you call terminate (or alternatively set the variable directly)